# Where and how to store login data

Tags: c++, encryption

I need to create a desktop application via C++ that could store previous successful connections to show it for user next time. What is the best practice to store such login data? Is it acceptable to store it in the encrypted form inside some file or DB? If yes, what type of encryption is the best for such purpose?

Answer (score 0):

the main problem of storing login data is, that you have to retrieve it and you want retrieve it without user input some password. so the password is decodeable by design and the only protection of the password is security through obscurity. so it does not really matter how you encode the password since Joe Badguy can retrieve it in any case. just do not save it in plain text or some "encryption" like XOR. also maybe do not name the parameter "password=" to make detection a bit more difficult.